# jQuery Validation in ASP.NET and AngularJS

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs, jquery-validate

I want to perform jQuery Validation on a form before submitting to AJAX. One thing to note here is that my application is in **ASP.NET Web Forms** with Master Pages implemented, and I already have a form with runat="server" in my master page.

In my content page, this is what the form looks like

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" id="PageForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="DesignationName" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-2 control-label">Designation Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="DesignationName" ng-model="newDesignation.DesignationName" type = "text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" >
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-sm-2 control-label">Designation Short Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="DesignationShortName" ng-model="newDesignation.DesignationShortName" type = "text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" >
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-sm-2 control-label">Designation Order</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="DesignationOrder" ng-model="newDesignation.DesignationOrder" type = "text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" >
                        </div>
                    </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Administrative Department</label>


                                    <div class="col-sm-8">

                                        <select class="form-control" id="DivisionId" data-ng-options="d.DivisionId as d.DivisionName for d in divisions"  data-ng-model="newDesignation.DivisionId">
                                            <option value="">Please select</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <span class="mandatoryFieldMarker">*</span>

                                    </div>
                       </div>



                    <div class="btn-list" style="text-align: right; margin-right: 1.5%">

                            <button id="SaveBtn" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-clickkk="save()"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="cancel()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Cancel</a>

                    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, I have used a lot of AngularJS directives here because ultimately I want to perform an AJAX submit.

In my AngularJS controller I have this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


    jQuery("#SaveBtn").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        alert(456);

        jQuery("#PageForm").validate({
            rules: {
                DesignationName: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 200
                },
                DesignationShortName: {
                    minlength: 1,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                DesignationOrder: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true,
                    min: 1,
                    max: 1000000
                },
                DivisionId: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                DesignationName: {
                    required: "Please specify designation name",
                    minlength: "Designation name must be between 5 and 200 characters",
                    maxlength: "Designation name must be between 5 and 200 characters"
                },
                DesignationShortName: {
                    minlength: "Designation short name must be between 1 and 50 characters",
                    maxlength: "Designation short name must be between 1 and 50 characters"
                },
                DesignationOrder: {
                    required: "Please specify designation order",
                    digits: true,
                    min: "Designation order must be betwen 1 and 1000000",
                    max: "Designation order must be betwen 1 and 1000000"
                },
                DivisionId: {
                    required: "Please select administrative division"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {


                /////////////
            }
        });


    });



});
```

The problem is, when I submit my form, I get alert 456, but jQuery validation is not triggered, and the data is also not saved (i.e. the submit handler is also not triggered)

This is my first time with jQuery validation, so I am really confused on what to do.

Comment: jQuery and Angular are two completely different JavaScript frameworks.  Why would you use jQuery Validate plugin with Angular when Angular has its own validation plugin??  And have you disabled ASP's built-in unobtrusive validation?

Answer (score 0):

Your whole problem is from trying to use a `click` handler and preventing the default behaviors...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#SaveBtn").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        alert(456);

        jQuery("#PageForm").validate({
            ....
```

The jQuery Validate plugin automatically captures the click event of any `type="submit"` button, so all you need to do is initialize the plugin and the rest is automatic...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#PageForm").validate({ 
        ...
```

---

**EDIT**:

Additionally, for this plugin, a `name` attribute is mandatory on every `input` and the `.validate()` method must use this `name` within the `rules` & `messages` objects.

```
jQuery("#PageForm").validate({
    rules: {
        DesignationName: { // <- MUST be the NAME attribute
            ....
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/06q8sxa3/](https://jsfiddle.net/06q8sxa3/)**

Comment: if I do that the form automatically post backs to the server

Comment: @Shuaib, then there is something else wrong.  See my edit... you MUST have a `name` attribute on these inputs.

Comment: I edited my form keeping name attributes along with id ... but the result is the same

Comment: @Shuaib, then there is something wrong you are not showing us.  This is YOUR code and it's working for me:   http://jsfiddle.net/06q8sxa3/